# Overlay background does not fill all container height

Tags: html, css

There is a .wrapper with `min-height: calc(50% - 30px)`and the overlay blur div which should fit all .wrapper height . Codepen https://codepen.io/palaniichukdmytro/pen/YzwMBKW?editors=1100

[image]

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: add `position: relative;` to your `.wrapper`

Comment: @SafwanSamsudeen the .blur will not fit all .wrapper container on mobile

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have / add `position relative` in your `.wrapper` as you have `postion: absolute` in your `.blur` class.

```css
.wrapper {background-color: tomato;
    border: 1px solid #dfe0e3;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin: calc(30px/ 2) auto;
    min-height: calc(50vh - 30px);
    height: auto;
    font-size: 70px;
    position: relative;
}

.blur {
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
    background-color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.3;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 3;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><div class="blur"></div>fdskfjdksfjfjklsdjfkdls Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut minus error earum excepturi hic reiciendis officia libero molestias magni voluptas? Quidem aperiam perferendis consequuntur vero atque ipsum sed voluptate optio.</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that was my bad, I've got position relative on .wrapper but only on desktop screen))) not mobile. So that is why it was confuse simple issue, thanks all